# xbindkeys in ubuntu loses mouse button presses on some windows

Tags: xorg

I'd like to assign my forward and back buttons to switch workspaces. I've made scripts called "goleft" and "goright"

and added this to my xbindkeysrc

```
"~/bin/goleft"
  b:8 + Release

"~/bin/goright"
  b:9 + Release
```

it ALMOST works. The back and forward buttons run the commands, but only when I click on some windows, like chrome. not when i click on a terminal, or the ubuntu desktop. there the button presses are swallowed for some reason :(